# One of the following two matrix is symmetric positive definite?

Tags: matrices

Recently, I com across a questions, which can be given as follows,

If there are two symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $W$ and $T$, but they satisfy the following condition: $null(W)\cap null(T) = \{0\}$, where $null(·)$ denotes the null space of the corresponding matrix.

Then can we obtain that one of these two matrices is symmetric positive definite?

Comment: Consider matrices $\left[\matrix{1 & 0\\0 & 0}\right]$ and $\left[\matrix{0 & 0\\0 & 1}\right]$.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Many thanks.